# Getting error when attempting to remove hidden names in excel

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to run a macro to clear my workbook of hidden names so when a tab is copied I don't have to hold down enter for 5 minutes because of all of the hidden names.

I looked around for some VBA code to accomplish this but am getting the error:

> "Run-time error '1004': The syntax of this name isn't correct."

I assume it's running into an invalid name so it can't delete it?

Code below:

```
Sub Remove_Hidden_Names()

    Dim xName As Variant

    If MsgBox("Do you really want to delete all hidden names in this workbook?", vbQuestion + vbYesNoCancel, "Delete hidden names?") = vbYes Then

        For Each xName In ActiveWorkbook.Names
            If xName.Visible = False Then
                xName.Delete
            End If
        Next xName

        MsgBox "All hidden names in this workbook have been deleted.", vbInformation + vbOKOnly, "Hidden names deleted"
    End If
    
End Sub
```

Comment: What line? What is the value of `xName` at the time you get this message?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. I Hit alt + F8 and choose the macro to run and then I get the error. It doesn't tell me a specific name. I did just hit debug and it highlighted xName.Delete.

Comment: Hover over `xName` when in debug mode and you can see what value it has.

Comment: If you examine the `Locals` window after hitting debug, it will show `xName` and a value after it.  You can also type (while the macro is halted by debug), `?xName` `<Enter>` into the Immediate window.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like there might be an invalid or corrupted name, the box shouldn't allow for dashe or hyphens. You could try to open the XML of the worksheet, find the invalid name and change it to a valid one.

Answer (score 0):

From elsewhere in this forum, it seems name.delete problem occurs when the name is an internal name created by Excel.  Such names start with "Xlfn" and cannot be deleted.